# Is there a way to programatically generate the adf_publish content in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am new to Azure Data Factory and reading thorugh the docs I found that to generate an artifact to deploy to other DF envs, you need to publish in the dev DF, which generates an adf_publish branch with the jsons to deploy. My question is whether I can run this publish programatically and thus generate the jsons from any branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the only way to update the 'adf_publish' branch is by manually clicking the publish button in the UX.

The product group is currently designing a solution to be able to do this programmatically via a DevOps build task. No exact ETA unfortunately.

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: Here is the uservoice link: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/40556329-please-allow-users-to-automate-publish

We are actively developing this right now and current ETA is early 2021 if everything goes according to plan

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about programmatically publishing to adf_publish.

But, it's very possible to skip the adf_publish branch entirely and deploy using [Azure DevOps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2vcXIiSD8-Y) or [PowerShell](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BhQE_D1m76g) straight from the source json instead.